# Thousands of backlinks from Meetup.com

Tags: seo, links, backlinks

I have been wondering something for a while now. We have a manual penalty from Google on unnatural linking. When I check out "Links to your site" in Webmaster Tools we have 11,387 links from Meetup.com. Is this harming us? After clicking through some of the links randomly I have discovered it is from one of our dealers that sells our products. He is sponsoring different groups and so the ad appears, the problem is he is linking back to our site and not his own. The anchor text is all the same it never changes.

Comment: Yes, it may be an issue. But need to know some specification: what is anchor text? Agressive commerce or like url of your site or words like "here, source, this site"? And second - are the links dofollow?

Answer (score 1):

Although your intentions are clear, still I think that that too many links from a single domain can harm your website rankings. 
There are various strategies you can apply:

1. If the back links are coming from a dealer's selling items page, is
   there any way that you ask him not to use your link any more?
2. You can start creating some more relevant back links to your website. In this way your back links will be diverted. Remember back
   links diversity is very important.
3. Don`t know if you are able to do, if the link that you dealer is using has nothing to do with the website and he is just using as the promoting item, this is called a bad link. Removing bad links is better than creating some junk back links.

I hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

Your dealer may be doing a good job of promoting your product! You have to decide. I am assuming that he is making the exact same link (cut and paste) each time he sets up a meeting or makes a connection. If this is the case, he is very aggressive about selling. That may be good or that may be bad. That is up to you to decide.

Here is what I am assuming. On meetup.com there are 11,387 that all look exactly the same and of course, Google is concerned about unnatural linking. It is!

I am assuming that your dealer would be the only one to modify or remove the links. You will have to begin working with the dealer to remove these links. This is important enough that you may want to consider suspending their ability to sell your products while this is being fixed. Then I would do a manual review of the dealers practices. I am not saying that the dealer is a bad one. They may be, or just unaware of the consequences of linking the way they do. They have likely crossed over to spamming meetup.com. It may have been intentional, but I doubt it.

You will want to create or modify an existing page that defines these kinds of activity parameters that helps your dealers sell your product. I advise businesses in your situation to create a large variety of linking schemes, images, logos, and what not and make it a cut and paste option for re-sellers. You may also want to create varying marketing copy that they can use. Keep in mind that people tend to take just the top few of any choice you provide. This means that you will want to randomize your page so that selecting the top few will result in variety in the future.

You have to remove these links somehow. Work with your dealer to remove them. Remember that you attract more bees with honey! (Remember that bees are good, they fertilize crops.) Do what you can to be kind and gentle and assume the best intentions. But remove these links! Perhaps, the re-seller can provide log in details and your staff can help. Removing these links has to become priority one since it is effecting your ability to conduct business.